# How to monitor when a file/folder is moved, and where it moved to?

Tags: linux, monitoring, filesystems

I'm looking for a way to monitor when a file/folder is moved, as well as where it was moved to.

So far in my research I've come across tools such as `auditd`, `watch` and `inotify`. While these tools are great at monitoring when a file moves, they don't keep track of where the file moved to.

I have also looked at the syslogs generated when a file is moved but they are painful to read/parse.

Are there any tools out there than can perform this function? Or should I start writing my own script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get the functionality to work with `auditd`.

The following command monitors

`auditctl -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S rename,rmdir,unlink,unlinkat,renameat -F dir=/path/to/folder/to/monitor -F key=DONT_MOVE`

The key can be any string of your choice, and will be used to filter audit logs for this specific entry.

For persistence, you can append the above string without `auditctl` to `/etc/audit/audit.rules`.

To check if/where the folder moved, run `ausearch -k DONT_MOVE`. The logs are not very human friendly, but they do list the timestamp and to/from paths.